# Weird behaviour in Nginx response header for internal redirects

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I have two upstream servers A (tomcat) and B (tomcat).
From server A, i'm sending an internal redirect with "X-Accel-Redirect" header and in the nginx.conf, I've redirected this to the server B.

From server B, I'm sending a file in response and I set the content type of the response to be `application/x-x509-ca-cert`. And then obviously Nginx forwards this to the client. But the response header sent by Nginx to the client is like `application/x-x509-ca-cert; charset=ISO-8859-1`.

I customized the logs output and the access.log looks like

```
application/x-x509-ca-cert application/x-x509-ca-cert; charset=ISO-8859-1 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2021:15:55:13] "GET /uri" 200
```

Through trial and errors, I've concluded that this charset is only appended during internal redirects.
One such test is done with only one upstream server B and serving the response directly without any internal redirects.
In that case, log looks like

```
application/x-x509-ca-cert application/x-x509-ca-cert 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2021:15:55:13] "GET /uri" 200
```

Please explain why this is happening during internal redirects. I found a solution to strip this charset and readding the "Content-Type" header.

But I would like to understand why this behaviour is observed during internal redirects.

My nginx.conf looks like

```
events {
     worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
     log_format  custom  '$upstream_http_content_type $sent_http_content_type $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

     access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;

     
     upstream A {
          server A:444;
     }

     upstream B {
          server B:442;
     }

     server {
          listen 8445;
          listen 443 ssl;
          server_name A;
          underscores_in_headers on;
          
          location / {
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
               if ($http_cookie ~ 'A') {
                    proxy_pass https://A;
                    break;
               }

               proxy_pass https://B;
               proxy_redirect https://B/ https://$host:$server_port/;
          }

        location @internalRedirect {
            internal;
             proxy_set_header Host            $host;
             proxy_set_header customHeader true;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
             proxy_pass https://B;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. The request is made by the client. This is referred as the main request.
2. The request gets sent to upstream server A.(In my case, the redirection is done based on a cookie value in the request header)
3. `X-Accel-Redirect` header with `@internalRedirect` is provided by server A.
4. Nginx makes a ***subrequest*** to server B.

We need to understand 2 things here.

I) From [Nginx Official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html),

> It should be noted that if a response is received in a subrequest then the conversion from the response charset to the main request charset is always performed, regardless of the override_charset directive setting.

II) From [apache doc referencing Http specification](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Character+Encoding)

> Default Encoding for POST:
> Older versions of the HTTP/1.1 specification (e.g. RFC 2616) indicated that ISO-8859-1 is the default charset for text-based HTTP request and response bodies if no charset is indicated.

For GET requests, I'm not able to find a doc explicitly stating default content type. But based on my current experience, I assume it to be ISO-8859-1.

---

So, combining the two info above.

1. The client makes a request to Nginx (without any character encoding, thus implicitly it is `ISO-8859-1`).
2. After getting internal redirect flag from upstream, Nginx makes a subrequest and gets the response. Then Nginx overrides the character encoding present in the subrequest's response header with the character encoding present in the main request header.